# Group proxyAddress - Cannot Update from Graph API - Get Permissions Issue

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-groups

It is unlikely that the account that I'm using to call Graph API doesn't have adequate permissions, but whenever I modify proxyAddress property of a Office 365 Group, I receive the following error,

```
{
   "error": {
       "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
       "message": "The requesting application is not authorized to set group proxy addresses.",
       "innerError": {
           "date": "2022-01-17T12:01:39",
           "request-id": "328be4b4-eb20-483e-adf7-bb02dfae3be2",
           "client-request-id": "cabb604f-b315-be14-9ba0-9b0571ba7b1b"
       }
   }
}
```

If I PATCH without modifying the proxyAddress property at all, then I don't get this error, but whenever I modify the payload for proxyAddress at all, I get this error.

Example, PATCH:

```
{
    "proxyAddresses": [
        "SPO:SPO_269b2269-296d-43f4-b67e-88b6f32a7fcd@SPO_af6dd7da-54b5-411e-bab8-0b31f96e9e42",
        "smtp:twg35@lincdev.com",
        "SMTP:twg35aaa@lincdev.com",
        "smtp:twg35@linc.onmicrosoft.com",
        "smtp:twg35aab@lincdev.com"
    ]
}
```

I can change other properties and I can successfully set proxyAddress when I create the group, but updates always fail with error.  Also, I've tried updating the mailNickname property and this has no effect.  I can also update this value from the Office 365 Admin UI by modifying the email (primary / alias) and accomplish exactly what I'm after.

Can someone confirm that this isn't possible via Graph API or can you confirm / help me with the process or permission to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

According the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/group?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties) group `proxyAddresses` is read-only property. It cannot be updated.